# FullCalendar v5 change event size in Angular

Tags: css, angular, fullcalendar

Using

```
this.calendarOptions.defaultAllDay = true;
this.calendarOptions.eventDisplay = 'display';
```

I want to change the size of the event to color all cell (month view), i discard eventdisplay background because i need use drag and drop.

I want this or similar but with drag and drop activated
[Full calendar event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNsy9.png)

CSS its not working

```
.event-class .cal-event-title {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas? thx

EDIT

```
<a class="fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-event-draggable fc-event-resizable fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future clasePrueba" style="background-color: rgb(189, 224, 254);">
    <div class="fc-event-main">
     <div class="fc-event-main-frame">
      <div class="fc-event-title-container">
       <div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">TEST</div>
    </div>
     </div>
      </div>
        <div class="fc-event-resizer fc-event-resizer-end">
    </div></a>
```

Comment: Add YOUR code not an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:host` with `:ng-deep` to style the element inside the fullCalander's component(put the css in your component css file)

```
:host full-calendar::ng-deep{
.event-class{
//your style
  }
}
```

Comment: happy to help:)